# Find the remainder when $2^{2003}$ is divided by $17$ without congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The title says it all.I can solve it using Fermat's little theorem.But I cannot use it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:-

$2^{2003}=2^{2000}*2^3=(2^4)^{500}*8=(17-1)^{500}*8$

Expanding this by binomial we get a number of the form-

$$(17K+1)*8$$=$$17M+8$$

[There is a $+1$ term since,last term is $(-1)^{500}$.]

It is easy to derive remainder when $17$ divides $17M+8$.

Answer (score 2):

${\rm mod}\ 17\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{2^{\large 4}\equiv -1}\,\Rightarrow\,2^{\large 3+8N}\!\equiv\, 2^{\large 3}(\color{#c00}{2^{\large 4}})^{\large 2N}\!\equiv\, 2^{\large 3}(\color{#c00}{-1})^{\large 2N}\!\equiv\, 2^{\large 3}$